# colorbox doesn't wrap the text correctly

Tags: formatting, color

There is a problem with using `\colorbox` command. As you can see in the example and its output, the statements in the `\colorbox` doesn't correctly wrapped. Is there any suggestion for that?

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\begin{abstract}
This is an example to show that without using the colorbos command in latex, the text is correctly wrrapped as the formatting suggests.

\colorbox{red}{I am trying to understand how the colorbox command works in latex. As you can see, adding the a phrase inside the colorbox command causes the text to exceed the page boundary. However, I want to see a wrap!}

\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The Elsevier tex package is available [here](http://www.elsevier.com/author-schemas/latex-instructions).

---

**UPDATE**

Apart from the solution by SoundsOfSilence, which is a working solution, I found that `\usepackage{soul}` and `\hl{the text}` is much better and supports line breaking. More info is available [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/soul/soul.pdf).

Comment: `\colorbox` doesn't support line breaks...

Comment: One should keep in mind, that if this should be an article published by `elsevier`, they might reject the color box in advance

Comment: If using soul \hl (great!) , you can change the color as such

\definecolor{myBlue}{RGB}{0,191,255}


\usepackage{soul}


\sethlcolor{myBlue}

[...]

\hl{This text is highlighted} and this isn't.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could introduce a `\parbox`, of width, say, `0.9\textwidth`, for example or use a `tcolorbox` solution.

Spacings could be adjusted by using *various* options

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{width=0.9\textwidth,boxrule=0pt,colback=red,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,left=0pt,right=0pt,boxsep=5pt}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{abstract}
This is an example to show that without using the colorbos command in latex, the text is correctly wrrapped as the formatting suggests.

\colorbox{red}{\parbox{0.9\textwidth}{I am trying to understand how the colorbox command works in latex. As you can see, adding the a phrase inside the colorbox command causes the text to exceed the page boundary. However, I want to see a wrap!}}

\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}
I am trying to understand how the colorbox command works in latex. As you can see, adding the a phrase inside the colorbox command causes the text to exceed the page boundary. However, I want to see a wrap!
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]