# Forcing mintinline background to have the height of the line

Tags: xetex, minted

I'm having trouble with `\mintinline`, because I am using a black background for it, and the characters render in a way that I find unpleasing. Namely, when doing something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{monokai}

\setminted{
  bgcolor=black,
}

\begin{document}

Hello, \mintinline{coq}{+}, \mintinline{coq}{*}, \mintinline{coq}{-}, can you have the same height?

\end{document}
```

I would like each character's background to take the same height, as I find the difference jarring:

[image]

IS there a trick I can use to force the height to be fixed?

Comment: What version of the minted package do you use (see log file)? I can't reproduce this behaviour with version 2.5, all boxes have the same height here

Comment: Fairly sure I'm also on 2.5... Might be relevant: I'm using xetex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of `minted` states that the `bgcolor` option puts `\mintinline` inside a `\colorbox`. Therefore, as a solution, you can define your own `\colorbox` with a fixed height and use that instead of the automatic colorbox used by minted.

To set the height of the colorbox, a `\parbox` can be used within the colorbox (as in, for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232491/).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{monokai}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\inlinebg}[1]{%
\colorbox{black}{%
\parbox[b][0.6em]{\widthof{\mintinline{coq}{#1}}}{\mintinline{coq}{#1}}%
}%
}

\setminted{bgcolor=black}
Without custom colorbox/parbox:

Hello, \mintinline{coq}{+}, \mintinline{coq}{*}, \mintinline{coq}{-}, can you have the same height?

\setminted{bgcolor={}}
\vspace{1cm}
With custom colorbox/parbox:

Hello, \inlinebg{+}, \inlinebg{*}, \inlinebg{-}, can you have the same height?
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great! Had to bump it from 0.6em to ~1em because I have some tall glyphs in there, but it did the trick!

Comment: I realized that `\widthof` on `\mintinline` returns a width that contains some left-and-right margins, making the `parbox` slightly larger horizontally than the original. Any workaround?

Comment: You can subtract a small amount (maybe `1pt`) from the width, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149045/how-to-calculate-a-new-length (two answers with different approaches, but both of them should work).